# Jquery multipart request not working against Spring MVC server

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload an ajax multipart form to a Spring MVC server. However, it looks like I am doing something wrong.

Here is my client code:

```
var $form = $("#upload-form"),
            url = $form.attr( 'action' );

var params = {};
$.each($form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
     params[field.name] = field.value;
});

var data = new FormData();
var file = $("#file-input");
data.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
     // url:url,
     url:url + "?type=" + params.type + "&text=" + params.text,
     type:"POST",
     data:data,
     contentType: false,
     mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
     processData: false,
     success: function(data) {
          console.log('received response');
          // self.hide()
     },
     failure: function(err) {
          alert(err);
     }
})
```

On the other hand, here is my server code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity createPost(@RequestParam("text") String text,
                                 @RequestParam("type") String type,
                                 @RequestBody MultipartFile file, Principal principal) {
    //blah blah

    return response.ok();
}
```

Also, the payload of the request logged in Chrome is

```
------WebKitFormBoundary1L9rKeQBA9CmaBEC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundary1L9rKeQBA9CmaBEC--
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: no error. Simply, the body of the request (file parameter in the controller) is null. Also, I edited the question to show what the request payload is. Maybe the problem could be about that?